# why does it not allow me to print "player 1 is x"

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, boolean

I am not able to print('player 1 is x'). what am I doing wrong.

```
def marker():
    mark = ''
    while mark != 'x' and mark != "o":
        mark = input('select x or o:')
    if mark == 'x':
        print("player 1 is x")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able" to print that message?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: please explain your problem properly

Comment: It's a typo - indentation matters in Python, the `if mark == 'x':` is not properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it throwing you any error ?, I ran on my local machine with Python 3.7 interpreter and it works fine after calling the method marker().

Comment: I was running it on Jupyter-lab and it started working today. I guess it was an error by Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end. Are you running this with a Python 3 interpreter?

If you are running it with Python 2.7, `input()` you will need to put quotes around your string input, due to `eval()` being called on the input, behind the scenes. Otherwise, it will interpret your input as a name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python-3) for more.

With Python 2.7:

```
select x or o:"x"
player 1 is x
```

With Python 3:

```
select x or o:x
player 1 is x
```

Just to cover all bases, you are calling this `marker` function later, correct?

```
def marker():
    mark = ''
    while mark != 'x' and mark != "o":
        mark = input('select x or o:')
    if mark == 'x':
        print("player 1 is x")

marker() # <---
```